# VS2022 cannot debug Unity 2017 project

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2022

I've read this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2022&pivots=windows

The Unity preference is right:
[Unity preference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NBgV.jpg)

The Game development with Unity for VS2022 is installed:
[Game development with Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3uza.jpg)

VS2022 can be launched by unity when double click the script, but shows the notice:
[VS2022 Notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZcX4.jpg)

Everything is working when I use VS2015 or VS2017.
However, VS2022 is not working. I cannot run the debug in VS2022.

Answer (score 1):

If there is another package previously downloaded delete it and Redownload the visual
But I recommend you to use visual [studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
Most Unity programmers use it because of its speed + high efficiency, and there are some packages for debugging codes

These are the packages to download:

[C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp)

[Debugger for Unity](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Unity.unity-debug)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried to reinstall the package and it doesn't work. I like VSCode but I'm used to the VAssist addon in VS. Is there any packages which can replace VAssist in VSCode?

Comment: yep, The accessories I attached above are the accessories you replace ^_^

Comment: I tried VSCode and the editor is easy to use, but the Debugger for Unity plugin is not working. The Editor freezes when the breakpoint is hit with nothing showing on VSCode. I can do nothing but detach the debugger.  I read the comments for the plugin and many people meet the same situation. Unity Technology seems not being maintaining the plugin any more. So sad... I guess I should go back to VS2015.

Comment: To be honest I've never had this problem before, I have Windows 7 and it works fine and I'm not thinking of updating it soon , I hope you find a solution soon ):